# OCT file and office 2010

Tags: activation, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office

I need to customize installations of Microsoft Office 2010 and was told that I need to use an "OCT" file. What is an OCT file? Could someone show me an example of using one?

Comment: It would be smart to ask the question in a way more than one individual could understand.

Answer (score 3):

An [Office Customization Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx) [OCT] file is created using a command line option of the Office installer.  It is executed using `setup.exe /admin`  -- This tool will generate a .MSP file containing your customizations.  You can apply this .MSP file using `setup /adminfile customfile.msp` or by placing the `customfile.msp` in the `Udpates` directory in the root of your Office install media.

Comment: +1, you can also place the MSP file in the Updates folder and Setup will automatically pick it up. Your copy of Office must have an Admin folder under the root directory or the `/admin` switch will report an error while trying to enter OCT.

Comment: +1 thats what I get for not doing a thorough search. Thanks for providing the correct answer, I can't say I have ever heard of a OCT file.

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for the additional details, the Admin directory is important to note. FWIW, the 2010 Professional install media I have contains this directory by default, yet our network install share does not. It is possible another technician removed the Admin dir. We use the Updates directory for our deployments.