# Example on OCT [Office Customization FIle]

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2010

Could anyone show how a OCT file is? How do I create it? Do I have to run `cmd.exe` to install office 2010? Can anyone show me the steps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCT file and office 2010](http://serverfault.com/questions/200318/oct-file-and-office-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can watch a video on how it works by following the link on the technet documentation page: [Import an Office 2010 Setup customization file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681791.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Basically create a shortcut to Setup.exe with /admin on the end, then configure a MSP file to your liking. Then when you run setup.exe use /adminfile:path\to\MSP.msp on the end